# When does $f(z)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{z^3}-1}$ has an analytic branch

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a difficulty to understand when a function has an analytic branch.
For example, for $f(z)=\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{1}{z^3}}$.
And if I have an analytic branch can i develop the function $g(z)=\sqrt[3]{z^3-1}$ for a Laurent series?

Comment: Find a simply connected open subset of $\Bbb C$ not containing $1,\omega,\omega^2$.

Comment: Let $f(z) = (z^{-3} - 1)^{1/3}$. You have to find the branch points of $f$ (show that $0$ and $\infty$ are not branch points). Then choose a branch cut going through the branch points (in general, it is possible for one of the branches to be analytic in a neighborhood of a branch point, but not in this case). If $\gamma = \{e^{i t}: -2 \pi/3 \leq t \leq 2 \pi/3\}$, there is an analytic branch on $\mathbb C \setminus (\gamma \cup \{0\})$. The binomial theorem gives the Laurent expansion around $0$.